# images are uploaded but I can't see them

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working at a CMS website , 
images are uploaded but i can't see them , and it shows me

In Inspect element its show me "failed to load the given URL" or "Failed to load response data" .... or

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) jpg

I will put here some tools , maybe you guys will help me to fix this out , because I'm done !I can't figure out

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```html
<?php if(isset($opened['id'])){ ?>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#avatar-dropzone");

//            myDropzone.on("success", function(file){
//                $('#avatar').load("ajax/avatar.php?id=<?php echo $opened['id'];?>");
//            });
        });

    </script>
<?php } ?>


<h1>User Manager</h1>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">

        <div class="list-group">

        <a class="list-group-item" href="?page=users">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> New User
        </a>    

            <?php 

                $q = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY last ASC";
                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

                while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { 
                    
                    $list = data_user($dbc, $list['id']);

                    //$blurb = substr($page_list['body'], 0, 300); // scoate decat primele 200 de caractere!
            ?>    

                    <a class="list-group-item <?php selected($list['id'], $opened['id'], 'active'); ?>" href="index.php?page=users&id=<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
                        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><?php echo $list['fullname_reverse'];?></h4>
<!--                        <p class="list-group-item-text"><?php #echo $blurb; ?></p>-->
                    </a>

            <?php } ?>      

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">

        <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
        
<!--Caracteristicile editabile ale paginilor-->
        
        <form action="index.php?page=users&id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" method="post" role="form">

            <?php if($opened['avatar'] != '') { ?>
            
                <img src="http://localhost/mywebsite/dinamiccms/uploads/<?php echo $opened['avatar']; ?>">
            
        
            <?php if(isset($opened['id'])){ ?>
        <form action="uploads.php?id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" class="dropzone" id="avatar-dropzone">
            <div class="fallback">
                <input type="file" name="file">
            </div>
        </form>
            <?php } ?>
    
    </div>

</div>
```

---------- my htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

-------and my uploads.php

```html
<?php

include('../config/connection.php');

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; //1
$id = $_GET['id'];

$storeFolder = "../uploads"; //2

$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newname = time();
$random = rand(100,999);
$name = $newname.$random.'.'.$ext;

$q = "UPDATE users SET avatar = '$name' WHERE id = $id";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

//echo $q.'<br>';
//echo mysqli_error($dbc);

if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //3
    
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__). $ds. $storeFolder. $ds; //4
    
    $targetFile = $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; //5
    
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile); //6
    
}

?>
```

I want to mention that i use dropzonejs but i think it doesn't matter because my images are uploaded , stored in that folder , but I can't view them. My connections with database are right .

That is how my folder looks , but i've tried to change the paths and still getting the same problem.

---

**Later EDIT : I found the problem !

```
if(!empty($_FILES)) {

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; //3

$targetPath = dirname(__FILE__). $ds. $storeFolder. $ds; //4

$targetFile = $targetPath. $name; //5

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile); //6
}
```

Here was the problem ,  instead of

```
$targetFile = $targetPath. $name; //5
```

I had

```
$targetFile = $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; //5
```

More explicit , When I upload the image , the converted name of that image goes well in my database , but It changed diferently the name of the image in my upload folder ...so It won't match the names from database with folder/path ...
THANK YOU for your support , I will try to help others too when I Will grow up in programming !**

Comment: problem with the image link.

Comment: That's a whole lot of screenshots and not a whole lot of question.

Comment: check image directory permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this 
in your image tag src="use here ci function as base_url()/pathname with img name" and also upload your image into asset/upload. so can access.

Comment: It's not a problem from paths , it's from php ,when takes out the names of images from database , now I saw this ... i'm still trying to figure out , Thank you for your interest !

Comment: once you debug your path with static location to get confirm if its not path problem and also directory permission. <p> <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $opened['avatar']; ?>">

Comment: @sschale   Thank you very much guys ! I found the problem and I put it above in my post (at bottom) Have a great day ! –

Answer (score 2):

When you see that icon, then it usually means it has invalid link to image. Try to right click and open image and check what URL it has. I usually see that it has not the URL I expect to see so it's probably the same for you right now. Accordingly to given url, try to find and fix a mistake in code.

Comment: Verified , it's the good location in the folder ... still don't show it  ............. Here is that piece of code `code`<?php if($opened['avatar'] != '') { ?>
            
                <img src="../uploads/<?php echo $opened['avatar']; ?>">
            
            <?php } ?>